# Magento CE 1.9.1 Guest Login "Please make sure your passwords match" error after upgrade from CE 1.9.0

Tags: php, e-commerce, magento-1.9.1

I am developing a Magento site and recently upgraded from CE 1.9.0 to CE 1.9.1. I have noticed that I now have an error when I attempt to checkout as a guest.

1) I select the guest checkout in step1
2) I fill out the form in Billing Information and leave "ship to this address" checked
3) When I continue I get the popup box with the "Please make sure your passwords match" error

In System->Config->Sales->Checkout I have the following

Enable Onepage Checkout = Yes 
Allow Guest Checkout = Yes

I have looked at a few suggestions from a Google search, including results on stackoverflow, and although they list the issue in their subject they do not seem relevant. The solutions I have seen seem to relate to passwords not matching and validation issues.

Can anyone suggest a solution to the guest cart login issue that seems to have popped up since the upgrade?

Answer (score 2):

this is a bit old, but worth answering... this seems to affect sites with checkout modules like Templates-Master FireCheckOut.

In the jump from 1.9.0 to 1.9.1, the mage core changed:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php - Line:840
$confirmation = $this->getConfirmation();
```

to:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php - Line:841
$confirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();
```

In the case of FireCheckOut, that means that I had to go and make the following change:

```
/app/code/local/TM/FireCheckout/Model/Type/Standard.php ~line 797 to:
if ($quote->getCheckoutMethod() == self::METHOD_REGISTER) {
    // set customer password
    $password = $customerRequest->getParam('customer_password');
    if (empty($password)) {
        $password = $customer->generatePassword();
        $customer->setPassword($password);
        $customer->setConfirmation($password);
        $customer->setPasswordConfirmation($password); // Added this line ***
    } else {
        $customer->setPassword($customerRequest->getParam('customer_password'));
        $customer->setConfirmation($customerRequest->getParam('confirm_password'));
        $customer->setPasswordConfirmation($customerRequest->getParam('confirm_password')); // Added this line ***
    }
} else {
    // emulate customer password for quest
    $password = $customer->generatePassword();
    $customer->setPassword($password);
    $customer->setConfirmation($password);
    $customer->setPasswordConfirmation($password); // Added this line ***
    // set NOT LOGGED IN group id explicitly,
    // otherwise copyFieldset('customer_account', 'to_quote') will fill it with default group id value
    $customer->setGroupId(Mage_Customer_Model_Group::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID);
}
```

By using both "setConfirmation" and "setPasswordConfirmation" you should ensure both forward and backward compatibility and not mess anything up.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that FireCheckout was pretty quick to update their own code and if you have access, upgrade before attacking your own code, but this applies to more than just Templates Master modules.